# Align Image Upload preview side by side

Tags: html, jquery, css, image, upload

Please I need help aligning my image upload preview in a row (to look like a brand/partners slider)[Current preview output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1fo8.png) but i want it in a single row.

```
<div class="image-gallery">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="cvf_uploaded_files">
            <li>
                <div class="user-img">
                    <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
                    <div>
                        <input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple" class="user_picked_files" />
                        <div class="green-btn-outline mx-auto mb-1"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="green-text small">Add Photo</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="overflow: auto;">
        <ul class="ipl cvf_uploaded_files">

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
  var files = this.files;
            var i = 0;

            for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var readImg = new FileReader();
                var file = files[i];

                if (file.type.match('image.*')) {
                    storedFiles.push(file);
                    readImg.onload = (function(file) {
                        return function(e) {
                            $('.ipl').append(
                                "<li file = '" + file.name + "'>" +
                                "<img class = 'img-thumb' src = '" + e.target.result + "' />" +
                                "<a href = '#' class = 'cvf_delete_image' title = 'Cancel'><i class='fas fa-times cross'><i/></a>" +
                                "</li>"
                            );
                        };
                    })(file);
                    readImg.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

The modern approach: flexbox
Simply add the following CSS to the container element (here, the div):

```
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

The old way
Use `text-align: justify;` on the container element.

Then stretch the content to take up 100% width

HTML

```
<div>
 <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt=""  /> 
 <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt=""  />
 <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    text-align: justify;
}

div img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

div:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```